# Can an app be archived when testing on a simulator?

Tags: xcode, ipad, upload, store

I am trying to archive an app to load to the store.  When I try to build it on my iPad it says can't because the distribution provisioning can't have a device tied to it.  When I run it on the simulator the option to archive does not show up.  My ultimate goal is to get this app loaded. Yes it is my first app.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you select appropriate provision profile for distribution?

Comment: I believe I have.  Where is that done?

Comment: Can a device be associated with a Distribution Provisioning Profile? I can edit and click select all and they check but they do not save. Should those checks save so that the Distribution Provisioning Profile knows my iPad?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot archive the application on the simulator.  You must select a real device for Archive to be enabled in the menu.  The issue here is around the certificate you are using.  You need to be sure you are selecting a valid distribution certificate.

Comment: I see.  When using the iPad I get and error that says "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found." But the distribution provision is loaded and visible in Library of my organizer but not in the iPad section because it says that "the profile does not include this device and cannot be installed thereon". How do I associate xcode, the distribution provision and the distribution certificate to each other?

Comment: You need to be sure your iPad is added in the provisioning portal for that provisioning profile.  Then delete the old one and add in the new one that you downloaded from the provisioning portal.

Comment: I am still battling this issue. From what I see, there is no way to add iPads to the Distribution Provisioning Profile. I can see the devices but they are grayed out. I have the distribution certificate.  I have the distribution profile. I select the iPhone distribution profile in the Target settings. But still get "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found" every time.  Very frustrating.